# Unable to use RSS Feed In Email

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am unable to get any output using the RSS feed in my email.
I have used the below code in the email content area directly -

```
%%[ 
var @xml, @isXML, @nodes, @rowCount 
Set @xml = HTTPGet("https://www.twill.net/feed/", false, 0, @CallStatus) 
set @xml = Replace(@xml, "dscblog:","") 
output(concat("Call Status: ", @CallStatus)) 
if indexOf(@xml,"") > 0 then 
  set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/rss/channel/item",0) 
  set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes) 
output(concat("rowCount: ", @rowCount)) 
  if @rowCount > 0 then 
    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 
      var @title 
      var @description 
      var @link 
      set @nodepath = concat("/rss/channel/item[",@i,"]/") 
      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"))) > 0 then 
        set @title = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"title"),0),1),'Value') 
      endif 
      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"))) > 0 then 
        set @description = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"description"),0),1),'Value')
      endif 
      if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"))) > 0 then 
        set @link = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat(@nodepath,"link"),0),1),'Value') 
      endif 
]%%
%%=v(@title)=%%
%%=v(@description)=%%
%%=v(@link)=%%
    
%%[ 
    next @i 
  else 
    outputline(concat("no items found")) 
  endif 
else 
  outputline(concat("no XML found")) 
endif 
]%%
```

Also, there is a tag <content: encoded> in my RSS feed, I am not sure how to parse that tag even.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

I am getting no output in preview screen -
[image]

Comment: What type of content block did you use for this?

Comment: I tried in freeform, HTML and code snippet.

Comment: Just to add, the same code is working fine in cloud page while executing it in browser via a cloud landing page

Comment: I would verify you are pasting it in the right spot and/or any outside code that could be altering it. I copy/pasted the exact code above into a message in my account and it worked fine in both HTML Paste Email and in an HTML code block.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to get the contents now using HTML paste, there was some issue with the template.